# How to sort object by a number inside of it

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, numbers

Trying to sort an object with some data depending on a number inside of it

For example:

```
    var object = {
        sort: 15,
        name: "Value 2"
    },
    {
        sort: 10,
        name: "Value 1"
    }
```

etc.

So I basically want to sort the object here by the 'sort' value inside of it. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: not a valid JS code

Comment: it has to be an array

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question. How sort an array of objects has been asked many many times.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array then use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to sort using a custom compare function.

```js
var object = [{
    sort: 15,
    name: "Value 2"
  },
  {
    sort: 10,
    name: "Value 1"
  }
];

object.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.sort - b.sort
});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

considering this example which is a valid js:

```
var myArray = [{
        sort: 15,
        name: "Value 2"
    },
    {
        sort: 10,
        name: "Value 1"
    }]
myArray.sort(function(item, nextItem){
  return item.sort - nextItem.sort;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about an array of objects. i.e:

```
var object = [{sort: 15,name: "Value 2"},{sort: 10,name: "Value 1"}]
```

In that case you can use [**Array.prototype.sort()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
var obj = [{
  sort: 15,
  name: "Value 2"
}, {
  sort: 10,
  name: "Value 1"
}]

obj.sort(function(itemA, itemB){
  return itemA.sort - itemB.sort
});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be passing a comparison function to the array sort function.

For example:

```
var someData = [{id:2, name:"Jacob"}, 
                {id:1, name:"Josh"}, 
                {id:3, name:"Trevor"}];

someData.sort(function(a,b) { return a.id - b.id});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!